# How to use impromptu for Jquery to act like a confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, return, impromptu

```
$('.delVid, .delUpdate, .delComment').click(function(){   //check deletions
  $.prompt('delete this entry?',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, focus: 1 });
  return false;
});
```

The classes are describing hyperlinks that when clicked delete an entry from MySQL.
I was using a vanilla confirm box before and having success, but I don't understand how to return a "true" or "false" from the impromptu box.
I think I have to use some kind of callback function, but I have been having no success =/

Answer (score 2):

If you check out this link:

http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php

It shows you on the RH column about 50% way down your answer. Here it is anyway:

Add a callback function:

```
function mycallbackfunc(v,m,f){
    $.prompt('i clicked ' + v);
}

$.prompt('Example 8',{ callback: mycallbackfunc });
```

The callback function has three parameters.

- The first is the value of the button
  clicked.
- The second is a jQuery
  object of the message within the
  active state when the user clicked
  the button. The third is an object of
  key/value pairs of the form values.
- The keys are the name attribute for
  the form element.

Comment: `'$('.delVid, .delUpdate, .delComment').click(function(){  
      
var returner = false;
      
$.prompt('delete this entry?',{ buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }, callback: confirmation,  focus: 1 });
 function confirmation(v,m,f) { returner = v; }

return returner;
 });` 

basically I'm trying to change my return value through my function.. but by the time I've clicked on a hyperlink I'm already returning false.. It's too late to change it to true. very confused.

Comment: sorry.. its so hard to get the code to be formatted correctly when you comment on a comment

Comment: i dug this up in case anybody wants it   $('.delVid, .delUpdate, .delComment').click(function(){   //check deletions
      
 var link = $(this);
$.prompt('tekst', {
callback: function(v,m){
if(v) window.location = link.attr("href");
},
buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false }
});
return false;
});